# Creating a stacked area chart

Tags: plotting

I have imported the following data from Excel:

```
s = {{{0.166667, 0.333333, 0., 0., 0., 0.166667},
 {0.0833333, 0., 0.166667, 0.0833333, 0., 0.166667}, 
 {0.333333, 0.0833333, 0.166667, 0.166667, 0.0833333, 0.166667}, 
 {0.416667, 0.5, 0.583333, 0.666667, 0.833333, 0.333333},
 {0., 0.0833333, 0., 0., 0.0833333, 0.}, 
 {0., 0., 0., 0.0833333, 0., 0.166667}, 
 {0., 0., 0.0833333, 0., 0., 0.}}}
```

My purpose is now to create a stacked area chart in Mathematica, of the kind shown in the diagram below. My question is, how can I do that using my data?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`StackedListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StackedListPlot.html):

```
StackedListPlot[s[[1]]]
```

[image]

```
StackedListPlot[s[[1]], FillingStyle -> {4 -> White}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `ListLinePlot` with the option [`PlotLayout ->"Stacked"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLayout.html):

```
ListLinePlot[s[[1]], PlotLayout -> "Stacked", Filling -> Automatic, 
  FillingStyle -> {4 -> White}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]