# How do I get Mathematica to show X = 0 (instead of leaving out this tick mark)?

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have no problem getting *Mathematica* to shift the origin in my `Plot`. What I have a problem with, however, is getting *Mathematica* to show the tick marks at the origin.

More specifically, I don't need *Mathematica* to show the Y-value at the origin, but I would like it to show the X-value at the origin in the plot below, where I have shifted the origin to X = 1, Y = 0.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `s` is from OP's [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184816/125):

You can use the option `PlotRangePadding`:

```
StackedListPlot[s[[1]], FillingStyle -> {4 -> White}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
    PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.01], 0}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]
  
Alternatively, the option `Method` with sub-option `"AxisPadding"`:

```
StackedListPlot[s[[1]], FillingStyle -> {4 -> White} , AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
    Method -> {"AxisPadding" -> {Scaled[.01], 0}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Finally, you can add the desired tick labels using `Epilog`:

```
StackedListPlot[s[[1]],FillingStyle -> {4 -> White} , AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},
  Epilog -> Text[Style[1, "GraphicsLabel"], {1, -.01},{0, 1}], 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: where did you learn about "AxisPadding"?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch,  tried ``Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot]``

Comment: thanks! Yet another good find from the `Charting` context. Wish a lot of that stuff was documented

Comment: The PlotRangePadding solution was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Your title says you want to show "X = 0" but your graph tick shows you want "X = 1" and your label seems to show you want it labeled "2".

Please fix your question.  And try this:

```
Ticks -> {Range[5],Automatic}
```

Comment: For some reason, that didn't work. But the crude AxesOrigin -> {0.965, 0} was satisfactory. It seems Mathematica doesn't like numbers at the origin?